# jQuery Session Timeout Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, session-timeout, timeout-dialog.js

I am using a jQuery Plugin for session time-out from Github

http://rigoneri.github.io/timeout-dialog.js/

Clicking on the Yes button is resetting the timer. But I want to do it from several places in my application whenever ajax calls are made. It looks like there is no way to destroy / reset  the timer. Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the invocation has a count down:    $.timeoutDialog({timeout: 1, `countdown: 60`, logout_redirect_url: 'https://github.com/rigoneri/timeout-dialog.js', restart_on_yes: false});

Comment: So when the pop-up appears, if I click Yes, it is resetting the timer.  But I have pages in my application that perform several ajax calls and I want to reset the timer after the ajax response is received. But I don't see a way to call the plugin and reset the timer on demand. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve with this possible.

Comment: While the dialog is open? Then you need to expose the count down value used here    `counter = settings.countdown;

        this.countdown = window.setInterval(function() {
          counter -= 1;` perhaps a question for the author

Comment: what can we do to return a reference / instance of the plugin so we can update the counters.

Comment: I doubt the author would respond. There seems to be an open issue logged in github against the same - how to reset the timer on demand - https://github.com/rigoneri/timeout-dialog.js/issues/7

Comment: I am actually interested in trying to fix it, I just have had no time and am vary of messing with someone else's code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$.timeoutDialog.keepAlive()` in your AJAX calls.